# Поиск элемента jquery

Tags: jquery, python

Есть структура html:

> <div>
>
> ```
>     <img />
>
>     <p>
>         <img />
>
>    </p>
> ```
>
> </div>

Нужно выбрать все теги `img`, метод `$('**div**').find('img')` находит только первый `img`, вариант 
`$('**div p**').find('img')` находит второй.

P.S. Использую библиотеку pyquery, поэтому перевел в виде jquery (возможно, упустил что-то).

**Вопрос:** как найти все img в блоке?

Comment: Думаю, что библиотеки отличаются только оберткой, вот наглядный пример, где ваш код полностью рабочий: http://jsfiddle.net/n14qxafa/

Comment: @AlexeyAl, Ваш первый вариант [найдёт все][1] дочерние элементы <img>. Можно и проще записать:

    $('div img')
    // но результат будет такой же, как
    $('div').find('img')

У вас или разметка "хромая", или вы что-то не так делаете. И закрывающий тег </img> не нужен

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/vonnoppx/

Comment: @lampa, как оказалось $ в питоне сопоставим с **puquery** приставкой
> pyquery('.content.content-topic-topic img').find('img').attr('src') 
- только первую ссылку
> pyquery('.content.content-topic-topic **a** img').find('img').attr('src')
- найдет вторую

Comment: @AlexeyAl, это не приставка, а функция ;) Попробуйте сделать так

    (function($){
       // тут весь код jQuery
       $('div img')
    })(jQuery);

Comment: @Deonis, с разметкой всё впорядке,я конструкцию сам смоделировал в спешке и оплошал.

Comment: Всем спасибо за обсуждение, но в **py**query  ...('div img').... находит только первый элемент(почему то не шарит на весь блок дочерниеэ лементы), не первый раз сталкиваюсь с этим из за слабой документации pyquery и моих знаний такие вот неприятности

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с синтаксисом, такой вариант решил мою проблему:

```
for i in g.pyquery('.content.content-topic-topic').find('img'):

           print pq(i).attr('src')
```